# RDLC - One page for each item in a list

Tags: report, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I made a report with many fields, which filled with properties of a class.

The DataSource is a class that contains many properties of string type. Up to this point, everything works perfect.

**Here my problem:** One of the properties is a list of strings. I need a page to be printed for each item.

Eg:

```
public class Student
{
    public List<String> Names { get; set; }

    public string Course { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the example, I need to print a page for each name, holding constant the other values.

As additional information, I'm not using tables, only textbox. This is why I need to print with pinpoint accuracy.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should still use some sort of control you can bind to your dataset and add group and paging rules. if you don't want to use table, you cam use list control.

Comment: @InitK Thank you very much for your help. I'm open to any idea. I tried using list control, but had either success, probably due to my lack of experience in reporting.

Add some information that may be important: my report does not contain header, either foot. This is due to the nature of the document, not a whim.

Could you guide me a bit more?. I appreciate your help, and the time you spend me.

Comment: I just re-read your question and see that I misunderstood it. I think your approach should be to create "flat" version of that data source - with only strings as properties - if you can separate other data as group header/footer. Or to "pre-wash" the data to have this list parsed into a string that you would want to display. Actually, what are the "Names" and how you want this list to be displayed as on final version of your report? You should add more details to your question and maybe provide little visual "mock-up".

Comment: @InitK Hello again. The report has no header and footer, because the document I am replicating does not possess. They are grouped information fields.

The report shall not process anything, the information comes "pre-washed". All fields are strings. Exept one, which is a list of strings. That is the list of strings that I mentioned in the first question.

I am trying that for each item in the list, a page of the report is generated. All other fields remain constant, exept that shows the list item.

If I'm not being clear, I will try to explain better. Thanks again!

Comment: I understand now, but I was talking about "group header/footer", not page header/footer. But you can disregard that, thank you for clarifying what you are actually trying to do. Since you need to have new page for each item in the list, all I can add at this point is that you need to change how data is "pre-washed" for the report and instead of having list of strings in that field - flatten the data to have one row for each page.